# Is there a way to combine these two LINQ statements into one

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I need to produce 2 separate lists out of 1 list. If company.IsNone is true, I want all employees added to the first list that match the locationsToCompare list, if its not true, I want all of the employees that don't match the locationsToCompare list. This is the exact opposite when populating the second list. Is there a way to combine these two if statements into one, or am I forced to have two separate to populate the two lists?

```
var noneEmployees = company.IsNone
       ? employees.Where(employee => locationsToCompare.Any(x => x.ID == employee.LocationID)).ToList()
       : employees.Where(employee => locationsToCompare.All(x => x.ID != employee.LocationID)).ToList();

var locationEmployees = company.IsNone
       ? employees.Where(employee => locationsToCompare.All(x => x.ID != employee.LocationID)).ToList()
       : employees.Where(employee => locationsToCompare.Any(x => x.ID == employee.LocationID)).ToList();
```

Comment: @MattBurland GroupBy would be tricky since lists can have non-empty intersection (due to `Any`)... I can't think of anything but `Aggregate` - but that look way more awkward than 2 separate `Where` calls (assuming code actually doing what OP needs).

Comment: Side note: code does not match description (Any(!=) and Any(==) are not opposite.

Comment: When looking for "employees that don't match the locationsToCompare list", don't you want to use `All()` instead of `Any()`? `Any()` would return true when it will encounter the first `location` that doesn't match the `LocationId` and what you actually want is the `employee.LocationId` that doesn't match *any* of the locations.

Comment: You are correct yes, the == needs any the != needs all. I will update accordingly

Comment: If locationsToCompare contains more than one element of different ID, either locationEmployees or noneEmployees will be equal to employees. This is because.Any( x => x.ID != employee.LocationID ) is always satisfied in this case. 

Perhaps what you really want to do is to check your definition of noneEmployees, and then take locationEmployees = employees.Except(noneEmployees)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, using `Except` so you don't have to repeat all the code:

```
public class Company
{
    public bool IsNone { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int LocationID { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

**Operation**

```
var locationsToCompare = new List<Location> { new Location() { ID = 1 }, new Location() { ID = 2 } };

var employees = new List<Employee> { new Employee() { LocationID = 1 }, new Employee { LocationID = 2 }, new Employee { LocationID = 1}, new Employee { LocationID = 5 } };

var company = new Company();

company.IsNone = false;

var noneEmployees = company.IsNone
                  ? employees.Where(employee => locationsToCompare.Any(x => x.ID == employee.LocationID)).ToList()
                  : employees.Where(employee => locationsToCompare.All(x => x.ID != employee.LocationID)).ToList();

var locationEmployees = employees.Except(noneEmployees).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

The group of employees is dependent on whether a company `IsNone` flag is set.

But before figuring that out, let us group the employees using the [ToLookup(TSource, TKey)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549073(v=vs.100).aspx) which is a dictionary/grouping type lookup where the key is whether the employee is in the `locationsToCompare` list.

Once the lookup is setup, we can the pipe in the company `IsNone` flag and extract the employees.

---

**Example Setup Data**

```
var employees = new List<Employee>
         { new Employee { LocationID = 1, Name = "Hamilton" },
           new Employee { LocationID = 2, Name = "Joe"      },
           new Employee { LocationID = 1, Name = "Frank"    },
           new Employee { LocationID = 5, Name = "Reynolds" } };

var company = new Company() { IsNone = false };
```

**Locations**

```
var locationsToCompare = new List<Location> { new Location() { ID = 1 },
                                              new Location() { ID = 2 } };
```

**Contains**

I will eventually use a [Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.110).aspx) in lieu of a where clause so I will distill the `locationsToCompare` into a list of ids.

```
var LocationIds = locationsToCompare.Select(ltc => ltc.ID);
```

*This step could be skipped, but I believe it makes it easier to maintain.*

**ToLookUp**

Now we use the `ToLookup` and then extract our lists based on company 'IsNone' flag:

```
var empLookup = employees.ToLookup(emp => LocationIds.Contains(emp.LocationID));

var noneEmployees     = empLookup[company.IsNone].ToList();
var locationEmployees = empLookup[!company.IsNone].ToList();
```

**Result**

[image]

---

What did the lookup look like? For it did the heavy lifting for us.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also extract the location ids into a separate list, and use that in the `Where()` clause, together with an xor for the `IsNone`. Combining that with the `Except()` operator solution of @leigh-shepperson, you get this:

```
var locationIds = locationsToCompare.Select(location => location.ID);
noneEmployees = employees.Where(employee => !company.IsNone ^ locationIds.Contains(employee.LocationID));
locationEmployees = employees.Except(noneEmployees);
```

I don't know if that's the most readable solution, but it makes it possible to make it shorter.